# CLIPSjni integrated JADE java

Tags: clips

I just started working with CLIPS integrated with Jade one agent.java, I have my facts and rules loaded in different .clp files, I already spent a lot of time trying to compare what I think are numbers but for some reason it doesn´t work, tried many different things nothing make it works:
Here part of my facts:

```
(deffacts products 
        (product (name "USB Memory") (category storage) (part-number 1234) (price 9.99))
        (product (name Amplifier) (category electronics) (part-number 2341) (price 399.99))
        (product (name Speakers) (category electronics) (part-number 23241) (price 19.99))
        (product (name "iPhone 7") (category smartphone) (part-number 3412) (price 99))
        (product (name "Samsung Edge 7") (category smartphone) (part-number 34412) (price 88))
)

And here I have the rules that are not working:
(defrule my-rule14
   (not (product (category smartphone) **(price<50)**))
   =>
   (printout t "no smartphones cheaper than 50"  crlf ))


;; Defining a rule for finding smartphones cheaper than 100 dlls
(defrule my-rule15
   (product (category smartphone) (name ?nameb) **(price<100))**
   =>
   (printout t ?nameb " is cheaper than 100 dlls" crlf ))
```

None of the rules are working I tried changing comparison to {price<100}, (price< 100), (price < 100), (price ?pricea) (test(< ?pricea 100))

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sections 5.4.1.5 and 5.4.2 of the [Basic Programming Guide](https://clipsrules.net/documentation/v640/bpg640.pdf) contain the relevant information for the syntax needed:

```
         CLIPS (6.4 2/9/21)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate product
   (slot name)
   (slot category)
   (slot part-number)
   (slot price))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts products 
   (product (name "USB Memory") (category storage) (part-number 1234) (price 9.99))
   (product (name Amplifier) (category electronics) (part-number 2341) (price 399.99))
   (product (name Speakers) (category electronics) (part-number 23241) (price 19.99))
   (product (name "iPhone 7") (category smartphone) (part-number 3412) (price 99))
   (product (name "Samsung Edge 7") (category smartphone) (part-number 34412) (price 88)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule my-rule14
   (not (product (category smartphone) (price ?price&:(< ?price 50))))
   =>
   (printout t "no smartphones cheaper than 50" crlf))
CLIPS> 
(defrule my-rule15
   (product (category smartphone) (name ?nameb) (price ?price))
   (test (< ?price 100))
   =>
   (printout t ?nameb " is cheaper than 100 dlls" crlf ))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      my-rule15: f-5
0      my-rule15: f-4
0      my-rule14: *
For a total of 3 activations.
CLIPS> (run)
Samsung Edge 7 is cheaper than 100 dlls
iPhone 7 is cheaper than 100 dlls
no smartphones cheaper than 50
CLIPS>
```